# How to align series and labels properly using customizer in Jasper report Bar chart?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have created a bar chart using iReport in which labels on x-axis and bars are not aligned properly. The chart looks like:

[image]

My SQL query is:

```
select LTRIM(RTRIM(SOURCE)) as SOURCE, count(*) as total
from CASE_UPLOADS
where UPLOAD_DT >= '20150601'
and UPLOAD_DT <= '20150630'
group by SOURCE
order by SOURCE
```

And here is some part from my jrxml file:

```
    <chart isShowLegend="false" customizerClass="com.test.customizers.BarChartCustomizer1">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="802" height="380" uuid="103d55c1-22d3-4446-bd88-3ea42654f43c"/>
                <chartTitle/>
                <chartSubtitle/>
                <chartLegend position="Right"/>
            </chart>
            <categoryDataset>
                <categorySeries>
                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{source}]]></seriesExpression>
                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{source}]]></categoryExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{total}]]></valueExpression>
                </categorySeries>
            </categoryDataset>
```

I tried to use some functions in customizer like:

```
    renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(--);
    renderer.setItemMargin(--);
```

And I tried to provide some values, but its not working. Is there any way by which we can increase the width of series so that labels and bars will look like aligned properly?